# Unable to delete attributes from QgsVectorLayer in Qgis 1.8

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-1

I have a layer with several hundreds of attributes in Qgis 1.8. I am trying to remove most of them, but in any case, it also fails with just the first one. I am doing

```
res = my_layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([0])
```

but **res** gets the value **false** if the number of attributes exceeds 403 (a quite extrange limit). Is there a limit of attributes to deal with? How can I overcome this issue?

**Update:** Example of the issue with three copies of the same layer on Qgis Python console. Same number of features (12), different number of attributes (405, 404 and 403 respectively).
[image: Python console]

Comment: What data format is the vector layer and do you receive an error message?

Comment: I do not get any error message. I only get the response as FALSE. I do not know how to debug it to get more information about why return value is FALSE. Data format is OGR sqlite.

Comment: is the field to be deleted an "ordinary" one, i.e. not the primary key or the geometry?

Comment: Yes, it is not the primary key and the layer has no geometry. The thing is it works if the number of attributes is lower than 403. I have test it with several examples. What my layer is, is some kind of matrix where I want to delete some columns.

Comment: Could you update your QGIS to a more recent version and test again?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I must work on 1.8 version.